# How to visualize polygonal planes in Mayavi2?

Tags: python, 3d, polygon

I have hard times to visualize lots of planes in 3D (e.g., of 4 points) using Mayavi2 with Python.
I couldn't find any polygon command within Mayavi2, tried to use mesh, surf etc but mostly unsuccessful or with problems. One problem for example in usage of mesh is:

```
x = array([0,0,1.5,1]).reshape(2,-1)
y = array([0,1,0.5,1]).reshape(2,-1)
z = array([1,1,1.0,1]).reshape(2,-1)
mlab.mesh(x,y,z)
```

I am not sure but I see mesh is not right solution. Because it makes you provide 2D arrays! which is not available.
Any comment and code snippet is greatly appreciated.
Developer